# SQL query get course number for certain student grades

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working through some problems and I can't seem to get the expected results for this one. The question is below with what is in my code right now and also the expected results. If anyone help that would be great. I'm just trying to get a understanding on this and can't seem to get my head around what exactly this is asking as you can see my code I have now isn't close to what the expected result is as of right now. Also I added the schema this will show whats in what table if needed for your guys help.

**Question**:

List the course number of courses wherein students have received grades for every one of the possible defined grade types. Order by course number.

My code so far:

```
SELECT g.Student_id, g.Grade_type_code
FROM Grade g LEFT OUTER JOIN Section s
ON g.Section_id = s.Section_id
GROUP BY g.Student_id, g.Grade_type_code
ORDER BY g.Student_id;
```

Any help would be great, also [here is the Schema](http://authors.phptr.com/rischert/documents/AppendixD.pdf).

DBMS: I'm using Oracle SQL Developer

Here is the Expected Result

```
COURSE_NO
----------
20
25
100
120
122
125
130
135
```

Note: The Chapter for this problem is based off using

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN
```

My Current results

```
STUDENT_ID GRADE_TYPE_CODE
---------- ---------------
   102 FI              
   102 HM              
   102 MT              
   102 PA              
   102 QZ              
   103 FI              
   103 HM              
   103 MT              
   103 PA              
   103 QZ              
   104 FI              
   104 HM
```

Comment: What results are you getting right now?

Comment: Look into using [Exists](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/exists.php)

Comment: Updated with my current results, I only added some because there is like 600 things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your ER diagram I believe this query should return a list of courses whose enrolled students have collectively received all of the grade types listed in the GRADE_TYPE table.

```
select s.course_no,
       c.descr,
       count(distinct g.grade_type_code) as num_grade_types
  from grade g
  join enrollment e
    on g.student_id = e.student_id
   and g.section_id = e.section_id
  join section s
    on e.section_id = s.section_id
  join course c
    on s.course_no = c.course_no
 group by s.course_no, c.descr
having count(distinct g.grade_type_code) = (select count(grade_type_code)
                                              from grade_type)
```

I didn't notice your expected result was only the course # (you can just get rid of the columns you don't want from the select list). Also the join to the COURSE table is only there to get the course description, so if you don't want the course description selected, you do not need that join.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select COURSE_NO instead. And also use JOIN and not LEFT JOUTER JOIN.

Something like this:

select COURSE_NO from
(
SELECT distinct (s.COURSE_NO) 
FROM Grade g JOIN Section s
ON g.Section_id = s.Section_id
)
ORDER BY s.COURSE_NO;

Comment: I actually was doing something like this but was using left outer join but when I do this it gives me like 100+ lines of the course_no how do I get the individual number because distinct won't work for me

Comment: you do not have to use left outer join. That is why you have more rows in the result.

Comment: I'm not using it right now but when I try your example with using distinct does not work I have to take it out and what this does is creates a list of duplicates